# VLOOKUP alternative to collect data from (sub range) as well for "GOOGLE SHEETS"

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, vlookup, spreadsheet

**Hello Spreadsheet Experts,**
Hope you all doing well,
first of all sorry for my bad English, because m not from an English country, but please try to understand :)

[My Sheet link HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LY91TNYGVgw6cgRGY4c7HsDjjgp3P-eEqGsj3S-jId4/edit?usp=sharing)

**Quick Question:**

Please help me to find Vlookup
alternative to collect required
values from sheet 2,
for example In column B of sheet 1
"Payment Fee" Only collects
C3 "amount" that matches
C2 "Payment fee" rows and C1 of sheet 2
and C1 of sheet 1 "order number"

[My Sheet Link HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LY91TNYGVgw6cgRGY4c7HsDjjgp3P-eEqGsj3S-jId4/edit?usp=sharing)

**Detailed Question:**

For example:

> Please Enter a formula in Column B Titled "Payment fee" (Sheet 1)
> That formula matches the Column A (sheet 1) and B (sheet 2) order
> numbers, and find "Payment Fee" row in Column B(sheet 2), and
> Collects amount from Column C (sheet 2) and Paste to Column B
> (Sheet 1) , from Column C (sheet 2)
> And please apply same procedure to Sheet 1's remaining columns
> C,D,E,F,G and H.

[My Sheet link HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LY91TNYGVgw6cgRGY4c7HsDjjgp3P-eEqGsj3S-jId4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

use in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), 
 {TO_TEXT('sheet 2'!A:A), 'sheet 2'!B:C}, 3, 0)))
```

[image]